# How to create a custom view with rounded edges and two textviews?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I want to create a view like image below. My implementation has some linearLayouts. One root with a custom drawable to get the rounded edges and then others for the two textviews and view divider. Is there a faster and easier way to do this?

[image]

Comment: You could achieve that by customizing the `@android:style/Theme.Dialog`

Comment: @silentw you mean using that on the LinearLayout?

Comment: No, on the activity manifest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just 1 LinearLayout, the root one. The LinearLayout is used just to order other views. So, what you need to do is to use the vertical orientation and add two text views.

On the first one you set the background color to a light gray. And remember to use the gravity as center so your text will be placed on the center of the text view.

Comment: To get a divider, you can use a FrameLayout between them width the bakcground color black and height equal 1dp

Answer (score 0):

I dont have much time, just tried to give a quick sample. Here's my code for your question:

your_main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_bg.xml">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my text" />

     <View
        android:id="@+id/seperator
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv1" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2nd text here"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seperator" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

your_bg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:radius="5dp"
        />
    <solid android:color="#fff" />
    <stroke android:color="#000" />

</shape>
```